# Prolog - Select the greater value in a list

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm newbie in prolog, my problem is very simple, I just want to take an element from a list in prolog, the elements are like:

```
[[List],Cost]
```

As example:

```
Set = [ [[point1,point2,point3,point4],33],[[point1,point3,point2,point4],31],[[point2,point1,point3,point4],46] ]
```

I just want to take the greater one, in the previous example:

```
[point2,point1,point3,point4],46]
```

Thanks for your help.

Just to finish, what about if I want to obtain all the expensive lists(one per one)? As example:

Set = [ [L1,33],[L2,31],[L3,26],[L4,31] ]

expensive_paths(Set,Path).

L2;
L4;

no

regards,

lars.

Comment: Dear all, Any ideas?

Comment: HI guys,Thanks for your answers, they are really helpfull for me.

Comment: then do select one of the answers as accepted please, the one that was most helpful, so the issue is marked as closed.

Answer (score 0):

The following clauses will look through the list and return the element (and value) that has the highest value.

```
% find_max(INPUT_LIST, OUTPUT_ELEMENT, OUTPUT_VALUE).

% Clause 1 - Only one element in the list - must be the max one
find_max([[R, Value]], R, Value).

% Clause 2 - The head element has a greater value than the remaining elements
find_max([[R, Value] | Others], R, Value) :-
    find_max(Others, _, LowerValue),
    LowerValue < Value, !.

% Clause 3 - The head element has a lower (or equal) value than the remaining elements
find_max([_ | Others], R, Value) :-
    find_max(Others, R, Value).
```

Example use:

```
2 ?- find_max([ [[point1,point2,point3,point4],33],[[point1,point3,point2,point4],31],[[point2,point1,point3,point4],46] ], Element, Value).
Element = [point2, point1, point3, point4],
Value = 46 .

3 ?-
```

Comment: you ought to take this code to CodeReview. if you do, could you please ping me so I could comment there in full. just one hint: what if the costs in the input are sorted increasing, like 1,2,3,...,100? what would the call tree look like in that case? what is the computational complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow your datatype - list's - definition, case by mutually exclusive case:

```
find_max([H|T], X):- find_max(T,H,X).
```

only non-empty lists have maximum element;

```
find_max([H|T], Y, X):- Y >= H -> find_max(T,Y,X) ; find_max(T,H,X).
```

if maximum so far is still the biggest, continue traversing the list with it; else use the newly encountered maximum;

```
find_max([], X, X).
```

when the list is exhausted, take note of the maximum-so-far - we now know that *it* is the searched-for maximum element.

Notice how we pass the updated current info along as we traverse the list, and also we pass along the result variable (`X`) unchanged, to be unified with the result when it finally becomes known.

That's comparing the elements with simple `>=`; you should make your special kind of comparison predicate for your special kind of data elements of the input list:

```
is_greater_than( [_,C1], [_,C2]):- C1 >= C2.
```